# Load Python Dependencies With Conflicting Sub-dependencies

Tags: python, dependency-management, unicorn, angr, qiling

I have created two virtual environments (with `virtualenv`) for two dependencies I will be importing, namely Qiling (a framework for binary emulation based on Unicorn Emulator) and Angr (a binary analysis framework). In each of these virtual environments' directories, I have downloaded the latest said packages and its dependencies, because, for instance, each of the above said packages requires different versions of Unicorn Python bindings. Question is, how can I import two Python packages with different sub-dependencies into my Python code, such that I would import two different versions of the sub-dependencies at run-time?

For example, doing the following will result in a runtime error with the Unicorn bindings:

```
import os
_SRC_DIR=os.path.dirname(__file__)
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(_SRC_DIR, "angr-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages"))
import angr # Quoting this line would allow qiling to run.
sys.path.pop(0)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(_SRC_DIR, "qiling-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages"))
from qiling import Qiling
from qiling.const import QL_VERBOSE
sys.path.pop(0)

def qiling_fn():
    ql = Qiling(["<path to my binary>"], "<path to my rootfs>", verbose=QL_VERBOSE.OFF)
    ql.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qiling_fn()
```

and the runtime error I get is the following (which means a Unicorn binding version mismatch):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path to script>/emulate_hello.py", line 17, in <module>
    qiling_fn()
  File "<path to script>/emulate_hello.py", line 13, in qiling_fn
    ql = Qiling(["<path to my binary>/"], "<path to my rootfs>", verbose=QL_VERBOSE.OFF)
  File "<path to script>/qiling-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiling/core.py", line 148, in __init__
    self._arch = select_arch(archtype, endian, thumb)(self)
  File "<path to script>/qiling-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiling/utils.py", line 394, in select_arch
    obj = ql_get_module_function(qlarch_path, qlarch_class)
  File "<path to script>/qiling-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiling/utils.py", line 80, in ql_get_module_function
    module = ql_get_module(module_name)
  File "<path to script>/qiling-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiling/utils.py", line 73, in ql_get_module
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name, 'qiling')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<path to script>/qiling-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiling/arch/x86.py", line 12, in <module>
    from qiling.arch.arch import QlArch
  File "<path to script>/qiling-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiling/arch/arch.py", line 9, in <module>
    from unicorn.unicorn import UcContext
ImportError: cannot import name 'UcContext' from 'unicorn.unicorn' (<path to script>/angr-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/unicorn/unicorn.py)
```

However, if I remove `import angr`, the emulator runs fine, because the correct Unicorn bindings are loaded.

Long story short, I want `angr` to import its own version requirement of Unicorn while `qiling` do so as well, from their respective import directories, and not have one common `unicorn` import for all packages.